# Why can't I save permalink "360" for a page?

Tags: permalinks

I am trying to save my page with permalink "360" but for some reason WP keeps updating the permalink to "360-2". I have checked everywhere in my WP and there is no page or post that uses permalink "360". Is 360 a permalink for something internal? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: So you're trying to create `example.tld/360/`? If this would work, then it might conflict with e.g. the year archive `example.tld/YYYY/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes with using only numbers as URLs. [Here is a forum thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalink-structure-adds-numbers-to-itself?replies=11) in WP that discuss this issue. I'll cite Otto:

> WordPress 2.3 and up does not allow the post or page slugs to be all
> numeric. This is because that URL scheme will conflict with multi-page
> posts.
>
> There is no fix. Change them to something else.
>
> Alternatively, a plugin exists to allow this, if you give up on
> multi-page posting:
> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-numeric-stubs/
>
> More info here: http://trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5305

Comment: Actually I haven't tried it in a long time. I've tried it a few minutes ago on VVV with WordPress 4.2.3. [Here is a screenshot](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/433972/b058729cc4fc74f85d35f0925e4fd441). It still doesn't allow you to use only numeric permalinks. Which WordPress version are you using? Is it installed from wordpress.org or with some script provided from the hosting e.g. softaculous and etc.

Comment: I was wrong, because it is a page, anyway I removed the comment, to not confuse others.

Comment: The *sample-permalink* ajax call can then be [traced](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/189833/26350) to `wp_unique_post_slug()`.

Answer (score 3):

If we check out the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3690) of the `wp_unique_post_slug()` function, then we see that this is expected for *hierarchical* post types, other than `nav_menu_item`.

If we try for example the slugs `360` or `page360`, then the `-n` slug suffix will show up.

We can play with e.g.:

```
echo wp_unique_post_slug( 
    $slug        = '360', 
    $post_id     = '', 
    $post_status = '', 
    $post_type   = 'page' 
);
```

or

```
echo wp_unique_post_slug( 
    $slug        = 'page360', 
    $post_id     = '', 
    $post_status = '', 
    $post_type   = 'page' 
);
```

to see that.

One of the "bad slug" checks, within `wp_unique_post_slug()`, is this one:

```
preg_match( "@^($wp_rewrite->pagination_base)?\d+$@", $slug )
```

It's matched in your case:

```
preg_match( "@^(page)?\d+$@", '360' )
```

hence the resulting slug suffix.

You can also play with it here:

https://regex101.com/r/jF3kC6/1

Note that it's possible to modify the slug via the `wp_unique_post_slug` filter, but one should be really careful doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did if you don't like plugins for a simple job:

```
// Fix issue with digits can't be slug
add_filter('wp_unique_post_slug', 'my_allow_numeric_slug', 20, 6);

function my_allow_numeric_slug($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug)
{
    global $wpdb;

    if (preg_match("@^\d+-2$@", $slug) && $post_type !== 'attachment') {
        $check_sql = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND " .
        "post_type IN ( %s, 'attachment' ) AND ID != %d AND post_parent = %d LIMIT 1";
        $better_slug = str_replace('-2', '', $slug);
        $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($check_sql, $better_slug, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent));

        if (!$post_name_check) {
            return $better_slug;
        }
    }
    return $slug;
}
```

`"@^\d+-2$@"` matches numeric slug with `-2` postfix.

I actually just check for `-2` if it has been added cause in the other case it means that you already have e.g. `360-2` page which seems weird to me, but I suppose you got the idea.